# Regarding :To find how to get the Sphinx Output data in a compressed format like gzip by making changes in source code?

Tags: sphinx

I've installed sphinx-2.1.3 release in a server and tested it by searching the data.It searches and produces the output in RAW format.But I need it in Compressed format like gzip..

Is there any possibility to achieve it?If possible where i need to make change in source code

Have anyone implemented to get the SPHINX result set in a compressed format? like gzip etc....If yes,please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really without modifing the sphinx source.

Although there is Compression support in the Mysql Protocol
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/compression.html
but I don't know if sphinx/sphinxql supports it.

Comment: Ya Thanks for the suggestion.will try that out.But I got a task like need to make changes in the source code inorder to achieve output data compression in gzip format.... if you get to know about any details by making the change in the source code,pls just let me know...Once again a big thanks for you....